# Can you update AWS ApiGateway not to respond to a port search for port 80?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had a security review recently and they pointed out that port 80 for our APIGateway end point is responding as closed.  As I understand this isn't an issue, but is there a way that we can configure APIGateway so that it doesn't return a response?

Sample `nmap` output for an ApiGateway endpoint:

```
$ nmap xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-08-12 15:51
Nmap scan report for xxxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.022s latency).
Other addresses for xxxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.REGION.amazonaws.com (not scanned): x.x.x.x y.y.y.y
rDNS record for x.x.x.x x.x.x.x.REGION.compute.amazonaws.com
Not shown: 998 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp  closed http
443/tcp open   https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.86 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The general problem with ports which are reported as "closed" is that they were reachable and they might be opened any other time. Administrators generally block such ports with a firewall. Then they would appear in the filtered state which means that Nmap cannot determine whether the port is open because packet filtering prevents its probes from reaching the port. I don't think AWS gives this feature out of box and you would perhaps need some external firewall to implement this.